# ThreeJS object outlines and masking

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have a problem with masking in Three.js.

I want to have outline around object and I did it using this tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8499/Generating-Outlines-in-OpenGL

I wrote this code;

```
renderer.autoClear = false;

...

renderer.render(scene, camera);

...

var gl = this.world.renderer.domElement.getContext('webgl') || this.world.renderer.domElement.getContext('experimental-webgl');
gl.clearStencil(0);
gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 1, 1);
gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE);
gl.colorMask(0, 0, 0, 0);

renderer.render(sceneMask, camera);

gl.colorMask(1, 1, 1, 1);
gl.stencilFunc(gl.NOTEQUAL, 1, 1);
gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE);

renderer.render(sceneOutlines, camera);

gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
```

and it works like a charm.

But i want to have outline more thicker. On windows, web browsers using angle and DirectX so i can render thicker lines.

(I know that i can use scaled object by vertex normals, but in this way i will create outline thicker in some places and thiner in other)

Then i got the idea, to blur outline.

I found this tutorial

(this is not a http link)://stemkoski.blogspot.com/2013/03/using-shaders-and-selective-glow.html

and i add MaskPass before rendering scene with objects that will be blured.
What happend then? Nothing.

I inverting mask and disabling buffer clear for mask and render passes but in overall i dont know what im doing.

This is the jsFiddle with some example that i made.

http://jsfiddle.net/9MtGR/15/

It looks like outline works but im using additive shader and green cube (that should work as outline) is added to red cube (that should receive outline).
Is it possible to use Three.js masking in the way that red cube will have green blured outline?
Or mayby is there other way to get the same effect using not Three.js methods?

P.S. This is a matter of life and death so it's not a joke.

Comment: You got your thin outline, blur it, then use blurred version and in post-processing effect just check if fragment has at least some value greater than empty space (fragment has been affected by blurring). I hope I made this clear. :P

Answer (score 1):

When I was working on some animation that required me to include star-wars-like lasers - that what helped in the end: http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-animated-selective-glow.html

Especially this example: http://demo.bkcore.com/threejs/webgl_tron_iso.html